# Cant install Eric IDE

Tags: python, pyqt4, eric-ide

I was trying to install eric ide on my pc. I installed PyQt4 package and I have python 2.7.
But the installation stuck with following error. I tried lots of searching but nothing found. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
E:\Downloads\eric4-4.5.16> python install.py
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 2.7.3
Found PyQt4
Found QtHelp
Found QScintilla2
Qt Version: 4.8.5
PyQt Version:  4.10.3
QScintilla Version:  2.7.2
All dependencies ok.

Cleaning up old installation ...

Creating configuration file ...

Compiling user interface files ...
An internal error occured.  Please report all the output of the program,
including the following traceback, to eric4-bugs@eric-ide.python-projects.org.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 1093, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "install.py", line 1011, in main
    compileUiFiles()
  File "install.py", line 906, in compileUiFiles
    compileUiDir(sourceDir, True, pyName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 134, in compi
leUiDir
    compile_ui(root, ui)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 126, in compi
le_ui
    compileUi(ui_file, py_file, **compileUi_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 175, in compi
leUi
    winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, pyfile, from_imports, resour
ce_suffix)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 139,
 in compileUi
    w = self.parse(input_stream, resource_suffix)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 943, in parse

    document = parse(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1183, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1643, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1507, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: Odd, I can't reproduce this.  Have you tried deleting the folder `E:\Downloads\eric4-4.5.16` and re-extracting the ZIP file?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I downloaded the tar.gz file. is it a problem? I'll try again anyway.

Comment: I used the zip and didn't have a problem.  I'll take a look at the .tar.gz file and see if that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

The tarfile within the .tar.gz file available for download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eric-ide/files/eric4/stable/4.5.16/) (eric4-4.5.16.tar.gz) contains 'pax headers', which it seems 7-Zip does not support.

These headers appear to 7-Zip as files.  You're getting an error because data from some of these pax headers is overwriting .ui files which should contain XML documents describing how parts of the GUI are built.  Of course, the data in the pax headers isn't XML, so you get an XML parsing error when PyQt tries to parse these files as XML.

This problem has arisen before [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/discussion/383043/thread/f9520ed2/) and [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.wikimedia.mediawiki.bugs/322583).  The latter even suggests (to me, anyway) that to generate a .tar.gz file without pax headers, you only need to remove a switch when you generate the archive.

It is inconvenient that this happens, given that 7-Zip seems to be the go-to tool for extracting .tar.gz files on Windows.  Given the popularity of 7-Zip, it would seem wise for the Eric developers to remove the pax headers from this .tar.gz file, if possible, as it would prevent further confusion.  I don't know if they have a reason for using these headers.

In the meantime, if you're using Windows, I'd recommend using the .zip file (eric4-4.5.16.zip) instead.

Comment: That tarfile is _not_ broken. I downloaded and compiled everything on Linux with no problems at all. Also, a diff of the unpacked zip and tar files shows the contents are binary identical. So it looks like there is an issue with the program being used to untar the file.

Comment: @ekhumoro: thanks.  I used 7-Zip, which is normally very good at extracting archives.  I've certainly not come across any problems with it extracting .tar.gz files before.  I'll have to take a look at how this .tar.gz file looks under Linux.